# Can an unsullied heart drop from any mob?

Tags: v-rising

Can an unsullied heart drop from any mob, or do only bosses have a chance to drop one? I have one, but I need more and have no idea which mob I got the unsullied heart I have from.

Comment: If you want Hearts for Greater Blood Essence you should kill Tristan The Vampire Hunter, he drops a recipe to craft them from regular Blood Essence. Otherwise you should just farm bosses or level 20+ enemies, there's no official answer to this at the moment.